# How do I find the absolute max and min of $f(x) = x^3 - |x|$ on $[-1,2]$?

Tags: real-analysis

I know the steps to finding an absolute max  and min, but I am not sure how to proceed with the absolute value within the function.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Consider two cases:  $x<0$ and $x\ge0$

Comment: $f$ is differentiable on $(-1,0)\cup(0,2)$; consider the points where $f'(x)=0$ and also the boundary points.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f(x)= x^3-x$ on $[0,2],$ and $f(x)= x^3+x$ on $[-1,0].$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \displaystyle x^{3}+x \quad \mbox{if $x \in [-1,0]$} \\ \displaystyle x^{3}-x \quad \mbox{if $x \in (0,2]$} \end{cases}$$
Now, note that $x^{3}+x$ is an increasing function on $[-1,0]$, so its minimum is attained at $x=-1$ where $f(-1) = -2$ and its maximum is attained at $x=0$ where $f(0) = 0$. For $x \in (0,2)$, the function is differentiable, with:
$$f'(x) = 3x^{2}-1$$
Note that this leads to $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ as a candidate for maximum or minimum. But we see that $f(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}) = -\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}} \cong -0.38$, which is not less than our $f(-1)=-2$ nor greater then our $f(0) = 0$. Besides, $f(2) = 6$, so we conclude that the absolute maximum is $f(2) = 6$ and the absolute minimum is $f(-1) = -2$.